# How can I add template suggestions by UUID?

Tags: theming, nodes

I'm looking for a solution to migrate content between environments (*dev->staging->production*) and currently I think I'll use UUID and Node Export (as far as I see UUID Features is still in alpha and isn't recommended by the community).

Sometimes I want to use template files or hooks (e.g. `theme_preprocess_node`) specific to a node created on my dev and then to upload the changes to production - this thing is impossible with the use of nids, but must be possible with uuids.
Is there any way out of the box to add theme_hook_suggestions by uuid, or do I need to implement it on my theme?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a hook in your template.php, like this:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {        
  if ($vars['node']->uuid == '12345') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'my-best-tpl';
  }        
}
```

Comment: Now I don't remember if it's $vars['node'] or $vars['#node'] :)

Comment: It is `$vars['node']`.  I ended up adding this line `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . strtr($vars['uuid'],'-', '_');` , so I guess there isn't an 'out of the box' functionality to do it. Thanks any way :)